# Perl complaining about global symbols needing explicit package name despite strict and warnings being off

Tags: perl

```
use utf8;
use v5.14.0;
@rocks = qw/ bedrock slate rubble granite /;
while( ( $index, $value ) = each @rocks ) {
    say "$index: $value\n";
}
```

output:

```
C:\Users\J\Documents\Development\perl>perl test.pl
Global symbol "@rocks" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 6.
Global symbol "$index" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 7.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 7.
Global symbol "@rocks" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 7.
Global symbol "$index" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 8.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I have read that not including use strict and use warnings enables one to circumvent this issue. But I've removed strict and warnings and here it is. I know it's incredibly dangerous not to use strict, but I'm just playing around with code. Having to type

```
my @rocks = qw/ bedrock slate rubble granite /;
while( (my $index, my $value ) = each @rocks ) {
    say "$index: $value\n";
}
```

is a bit annoying when you're just playing around.

It seems that

```
use v5.14.0;
```

is switching on strict or warnings; is that true? If so, how so?
And if so how do I get to be able to use `say` without having to prefix every sodding variable with `$my`? It seems I cannot use say without having the line `use v5.14.0.;` in my file.

Comment: Thanks. Got there at the same time :-)

Comment: Do as you please of course -- but it's not "_yadda yadda_".  It's equally important when you're playning -- that's when you _really_ can mess up.  And warnings are specially good (I always have that on even in one-liners).  Just how hard is it to type `my`?  If it comes up too many times perhaps you can evolve your testing manners so that it doesn't?  My opinion, meant as constructive and with best intentions :)

Comment: Ah but it's not my - it's $my. That's 50% more than my :-)

Comment: @JL_SO `$my`? You are mistaken. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html

Comment: @MattJacob yes you are of course correct, my mistake.

Comment: @JL_SO If you've found an answer, please post it as an answer. Don't edit it into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It seems that `use v5.14.0;` is switching on strict or warnings; is that true? If so, how so?*

The docs for this are unfortunately buried in [the documentation for `use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html).

> use VERSION also lexically enables all features available in the requested version as defined by the feature pragma, disabling any features not in the requested version's feature bundle. See feature. ***Similarly, if the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.12.0, strictures are enabled lexically as with use strict.*** Any explicit use of use strict or no strict overrides use VERSION , even if it comes before it. Later use of use VERSION will override all behavior of a previous use VERSION , possibly removing the strict and feature added by use VERSION . use VERSION does not load the feature.pm or strict.pm files.

> *And if so how do I get to be able to use say without having to prefix every sodding variable with $my?*

You can load features individually with [`use feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-'say'-feature). So `use feature "say"`. You can also load a pre-5.12.0 [feature bundle](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#FEATURE-BUNDLES) with `use v5.10`.

But you really, really, really want strict on. Really really really. Explicitly declaring variables with `my` gives you two important features: typo protection and lexical scoping. Typo protection is obvious, if you type `$receiver = 42` and later `print $reciever` you can spend a lot of time scratching your head until you realize you have a typo. This more than makes up for the time spend typing `my`.

Just as important is lexical scoping. This means the variable only lives inside the block it's declared in.

```
use strict;

sub foo {
    my $thing = 42;
}

print $thing;  # error
```

Without `my` variables are global by default. Any piece of code anywhere can touch a global variable at any time. This makes all but the smallest pieces of code more complex and more difficult to understand and turns them into ***NIGHTMARES*** for people who have to maintain it later. You also run the risk of accidentally using the same variable for two different purposes, particularly with a common name like `$count` or `$i`, mysteriously overwriting each other's values.